# MVC 6 passing a model from view to controller to partial view using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

What I am trying to do is create a gui object that can be used from all the different views.  The idea is to add the component as a partial view on the main view by placing the component into a placeholder div.

Here is my model

```
    public class Client
    {
        public int clientid { get; set; }
        public string clientname { get; set; }
    }
```

The java script that I am using to insert the component...
Ideally I would prefer to just use the Model data that is passed to this view by a direct call to it, but that was not working which is why I have been troubleshooting with the var model below...

```
var model = {
    clientid: 23,
    clientname: "This one"
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    url: "../shared/ClientProgramSelector",
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function(result) {
    $("#clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder").html(result);
});
```

The controller that is being called is here

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ClientProgramSelector([FromBody] Client passingData )
{
    return PartialView("ClientProgramSelector", passingData);
}
```

and finally, here is the div i am trying to place the component into

```
<div id="#clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder"></div>
```

The code is showing no errors, but nothing is rendering on the page.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?  Also, is there a way to just use the passed model instead of having to recreate the data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try replacing 'done' with 'success' and put an 'error' function in your AJAX call.

Comment: Is the ajax call successful  ? Is it returning a 200 OK ? Or a 404, If it is a 404, you should fix your url

Comment: The call is successful, I just the id wrong.  That was a stupid mistake.  But, would still like to know if you can pass the viewmodel directly in the ajax call, thanks.

Comment: Do not change your question and invalidate the answer (I have rolled back your changes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ajax success handler is trying to set the result to the jQuery element returned by  `$("#clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder")`. This will return the element with Id value "clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder". But your HTML, you do not have any! What you have is an element with Id `"#clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder"`

Your div id should be without the `#` and it should work as long as your ajax call is returning a 200 OK response.

```
<div id="clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder"></div>
```

If you want to render the partial view with the modal data passed to main view, you can call the `Html.Partial` method, Assuming your main view is also strongly typed to the same view model(`Client`) object

```
@model Client 

<div id="clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder">
  @Html.Partial("ClientProgramSelector",Model)
</div>
```

If you want to pass the original model as the ajax post data, you can use  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method in your javascript code block.

```
var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    url: "@Url.Action("ClientProgramSelector","YourControllerNameHere")",
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function(result) {
    $("#clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder").html(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, just noticed that while I was looking at the code.  Now, is there a way to pass the original model that was passed into the view from the previous controller?

Comment: You mean the modal passed to the main view where you have the div ?

Comment: Looking to pass the model in the view through the ajax.

Comment: I guess one more question.  All the styling and javascript from the partial view are not being passed to the main view.  Is that normal?  Sorry for that question, this is the fire time I have been able to get this to work semi correctly.

Comment: you should load the css in the main view in initial page load

Comment: I will play with it more tomorrow when I get a chance then.  Thanks a ton for all the assistance.